# Laravel 4: Possibility of modelling & validating generic objects OOP in mySQL database

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am currently experimenting with Eloquent ORM, and I am looking into the possibility of dynamically modelling an object within the application.

Let's assume that I have a shape model.

A shape can be a square, circle, triangle, rectangle, pentagon, hexagon etc...

All shapes have similarities, however some have different properties.

What I would like to do is make the mysql database tables more generic, e.g. create a table called shapes.

Shapes table:

```
id:integer
name:string
width:integer
height:integer
radius:integer
sides:integer
```

Shape Model:

```
$rulesCircle = ['sides'=>'required', 'radius'=>'required']

$rulesSquare = ['height'=>'required', 'sides' => 'required']

$rulesRectangle = ['height'=>'required', 'width' => 'required', sides' => 'required']
```

Let's now assume that there will be a form which asks the user to select and specify the dimensions of a shape.

Assuming that the user selects circle, we need the correct validation rules to be used.

This may sound like a silly example, however I am just looking into this for experimental reasons.

Is the correct way of doing this:

1. Use a shape model with different validation rules (if / else statements) to select the correct validation rule
2. Use a shape model for all generic shapes containing features common to all (e.g. name & sides) and square / circle / rectangle models which extend the shape model but all reference the same shape mysql table
3. Other

Is the above possible? Is there a better way of tackling the above? is there a best-practice way that this should be done? Is there a specific terminology for the above kind of requirement?

Comment: NOt sure what you are asking!

Comment: @SheikhHeera - I have rephrased the question / example given for clarity.